# Unable To Remap Modifier Keys With Ukulele

Tags: keyboard

I have a USB keyboard, and am trying to use Ukulele to remap certain keys. Though remapping works for most keys, it doesn't seem to work at all for modifiers (command, option, etc.) I also want this remapping to apply only when I have my USB keyboard plugged in, and want the mapping to set back to default when I am using the native keyboard. Help? I'm Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifier key remapping is already available in the Keyboard preference pane (hidden under a button).  I don't recall if it's per keyboard in Snow Leopard; it is in Lion.

Comment: You're totally right. I missed that. However, (and I'm trying to switch mappings of Command and Option), even when I use that,it still doesn't take effect on the keyboard (no idea why). Thoughts?